# Upgrade FullCalendar eventRender to eventDidMount for Right Click Action

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'd like to Upgrade my existing FullCalendar (v3.9 -> v5.7) `eventRender` to `eventDidMount` for a Right Click Action.

I have a webpage (FullCalendar v3.9.0) which has a right click action using the following `eventRender` code:

```js
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    element.bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var top = e.pageY;
        var left = e.pageX;

        // Display contextmenu and bind event for menu click events
        $("#contextMenu").show();
        $("#contextMenu").css({ position: 'absolute' });
        $("#contextMenu").offset({ left: left, top: top });
        $("#contextMenu").on("click", "li", { eventId: event.id }, contextMenuHandler);
    });
}
```

```js
function contextMenuHandler(event) {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    console.log(idx + '  ' + event.data.eventId);

    switch( idx )
    {
        // Miss 2 out as that is line separator
        case 0: cloneEvent(event.data.eventId); break;
        case 1: copyEvent(event.data.eventId); break;
        case 3: deleteEvent(event.data.eventId); break;
        default:
    }
}

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    $("#contextMenu").hide();
    $("#contextMenu").unbind().click(function () { }); // Make sure click event is removed from contextmenu otherwise it will fire multiple times!
});

function editEvent(id) {
    alert('edit');
}

function deleteEvent(id) {
  //if (confirm("Confirm Deletion?")) {
      alert('delete');
  //}
}

function cloneEvent(id) {
    alert('clone');
}

function copyEvent(id) {
    alert('copy');
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="calendar"></div>


    <ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Clone</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Copy</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
omitted
```

Updating to version 5.7.0 this has been replaced with [Event Render Hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks)

Is `eventDidMount` the correct way to go?

[Issue 2748](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2748) has a [comment](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2748#issuecomment-751405367) suggesting a vue version which I've modified below:

```js
eventDidMount: function (info) {
  info.el.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var top = e.pageY;
    var left = e.pageX;

    // Display contextmenu and bind event for menu click events
    $("#contextMenu").show();
    $("#contextMenu").css({ position: 'absolute' });
    $("#contextMenu").offset({ left: left, top: top });
    $("#contextMenu").on("click", "li", { eventId: event.id }, contextMenuHandler);
  });
}
```

The contextmenu will show, but when I click on one of the actions, like "Clone", it produces a *TypeError* from the `dispatch` in *jquery*.

```
TypeError: ((S.event.special[o.origType]||{}).handle||o.handler).apply is not a function. (In '((S.event.special[o.origType]||{}).handle||o.handler).apply(i.elem,s)', '((S.event.special[o.origType]||{}).handle||o.handler).apply' is undefined)
```

---

Example showing `eventDidMount` [tooltip](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo).

---

Samples

- 5.7.0 (from ADyson) https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRWPmMJ
- 3.9.0 (WIP) https://codepen.io/AlexHedley/pen/VwpqbdZ

Comment: Struggling to get a reproducible example of this - this is my fiddle so far: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRWPmMJ . But what plugin are you using for the context menu? I'm guessing I'll need to put that in before it'll show the error.

Comment: Sorry just updated the codepen with the rest of the code you provided. Aside from missing CSS, it's showing the menu successfully, no errors. Using jQuery 3.6.0 and fullCalendar 5.7.0. https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRWPmMJ . So unless you have some other code somehow conflicting with it, or you're using another version of one of those libraries, it's not clear that there is an issue here.

Comment: P.S. Just so you know, `.unbind()` is deprecated in jQuery - and has been for many years. It's recommended to use `.off()` instead - see https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Sorry I should have created some samples, thanks for going to the effort
I've started one for 3.9.0 (WIP) https://codepen.io/AlexHedley/pen/VwpqbdZ

For 5.7.0 I can get the contextmenu to show, but when I click on one of the items it doesn't show the `alert()` (or run the function I'll actually need)

Comment: Ok thanks. I've added the rest of the code into the 5.7 example. The alerts work fine: see https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRWPmMJ again. So if it's not working in your real environment I suggest a) checking what you've done matches what I've shown exactly, and b) stripping out everything else from the page piece by piece until you find whatever is getting in the way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and see what's different in my local example.

Comment: @ADyson do you want to add the codepen link as an answer and I can mark as solution?

Comment: I could, but...does it really qualify as an answer to your problem? All I've done is copy your code into a clean environment, and it works. That doesn't help to resolve why you've got an issue when you run it yourself. Have you now fixed that issue? Did you find the cause?

Comment: Fair enough, just thought you deserved some extra credit for your effort, appreciate you looking into it

Comment: I've got plenty of reputation points, but thanks. I don't want to post something which doesn't fully resolve the issue and is unlikely to be all that helpful to someone else in future who might have a similar issue. We really need to get to the root cause of your error message, and fix it. I'm happy to continue to help with that, if you can provide information which allows me to reproduce that issue.

Comment: Great thanks, still looking into it, will post back when I’ve got more info